# Find the linear transformation that is a reflection through the line $x=y$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Which of the following $2\times 2$ matrices corresponds to a linear transformation that is a reflection through the line $x=y$ in $ \Bbb R^2 $ ?
>
> a) $\begin{pmatrix}
> 1 & 0\\
> 0 & -1  \\
>  \end{pmatrix}$
>
> b) $\begin{pmatrix}
> -1 & 0\\
> 0 & 1  \\
>  \end{pmatrix}$
>
> c) $\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & 1\\
> 1 & 0  \\
>  \end{pmatrix}$
>
> d) $\begin{pmatrix}
> 0 & -1\\
> 1 & 0  \\
>  \end{pmatrix}$

I don't know to solve the problem.On Multiplying C) with the basis of $ \Bbb R^2 $ ,(1 0)$\to$(0 1) and (0 1 )$\to$(1 0).Is this the way to find the answer? Please help.

Comment: Show that reflection is linear, look at what happens to a basis, extend to the entire space.

Comment: There's a trick. Where does (1,0) go? Where does (0,1) go? Those are the columns of your matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First convince yourself that the effect of reflecting across $x=y$ is switching the $x$ and $y$ coordinates. Then in turn apply each matrix to $(x,y)$. You'll find that answer c) gives
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}0&1\\1&0\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}y\\x\end{matrix}\right)
$$
as desired.

Even simpler is to observe that if the point is on the line $x=y$, then it is mapped to itself. c) is the only option that acts thus.